# Does the Hawaiian Earring Group embed into the permutation group of $\mathbb N$?

Tags: gr.group-theory, infinite-combinatorics, fundamental-group, permutation-groups, embeddings

Recall that the Hawaiian earring group, $\mathbb G$, is the fundamental group of the Hawaiian Earing using the point at the origin. It can be understood more combinatorially as a subgroup of the inverse limit $\varprojlim F_n$ where $F_n$ is the free group, say with  $n$ generators, call them $a^n_0,...,a^n_{n-1}$ and $p_{n+1, n}:F_{n+1} \to F_n$ is the map induced by sending $a^{n+1}_i$ to $a^n_i$ for $i < n$ and $p(a^{n+1}_n) = a^n_0$ (say). The permutation group of the natural numbers, $S(\mathbb N)$, is the group of permutations of $\mathbb N$.

My question is simply, does $\mathbb G$ embed into $S(\mathbb N)$?

Note that $S(\mathbb N)$ does not embed into $\mathbb G$ since the later is torsion free whereas $S(\mathbb N)$ has elements of finite order. However $S(\mathbb N)$ embeds each $F_n$ hence the question.

Comment: Yes, since it's a subgroup of a countable product of countable groups (as a subgroup of this inverse limit).

Comment: By the way the usual word to say "has no [nontrivial] element of finite order" is "torsion-free".

Comment: @YCor thanks for the explanation. Can you expand just a little as why being a subgroup of a countable product of countable groups implies $\mathbb G$ embeds into $S(\mathbb N)$? I'm sorry if this is easy, I'm not a group theorist.

Comment: Because $S(N)^N$ embeds into $S(N)$. Just use a bijection $N^2\to N$, and take the subgroup of $S(N^2)$ preserving all horizontal lines. Here the left action induces a faithful action on the disjoint union $\bigsqcup_n F_n$.

Comment: Okay that's perfect thanks. If I understand correctly your argument actually shows that if I have a direct or inverse system of groups which all embed into $S(\mathbb N)$ indexed by a countable set then the corresponding direct/indirect limits also embed. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, this is correct.

Comment: It is a small thing that doesn’t affect the answer but the Hawaiian earring group is a proper subgroup of the inverse limit and is not the limit itself.

Comment: @JeremyBrazas thanks! Sorry for my confusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator\S{\mathfrak{S}}\DeclareMathOperator\N{\mathbf{N}}$Yes, because:

1. as a subgroup of a projective limit of a sequence of finitely generated free groups $F_n$, it embeds into the product $\prod_n F_n$.
2. each countable group embeds into $\S(\N)$ (just consider the left action)
3. If $(G_n)$ is a sequence of groups, each embedding into $\S(\N)$, then $\prod_n G_n$ also embeds into $\S(\N)$: just use the fact that the component-wise of the horizontal partition of $\S(\N^2)\simeq\S(\N)$ is isomorphic to $\S(\N)^{\N}$.

---

Side notes:

A necessary condition for a group to embed into $\S(\N)$ is to have cardinal $\le c$. For abelian groups it's necessary and sufficient. However, there are groups of cardinal $\le c$ that don't embed into $\S(\N)$. Example are the restricted direct product of any uncountable family of non-abelian groups, say, $\S_3^{(\aleph_1)}$.

Under ZFC+CH it's an open question whether every group of cardinal $\le c$ embeds into $\S(\N)/\S_{\mathrm{fin}}(\N)$.

Comment: Is it known whether it is consistent with CH that every group of size $\leq \aleph_1$ embeds into $S(\mathbb{N})/fin$?

Comment: @YairHayut I think it's unknown even with just ZFC (with ZFC+CH, this is what I already mentioned). I mentioned CH because there's a known model of ZFC in which CH fails (where $c=\aleph_2$ if I remember correctly) and in which some group of cardinal $c$ doesn't embed into $S_\omega/\mathrm{fin}$.

Comment: @YCor This is fascinating and exactly what I wanted to know, thanks! Do you know where I can find references on the side notes, particularly on the open question you mentioned?

Comment: @CoreySwitzer see the references before (10) p25 at my paper "Near actions" ([arXiv link](https://arxiv.org/abs/1901.05065)), when I mention Felgner-Haug.